# ¿Cómo aplico el Math.max al resultado de un contador?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando implementar esto:

```
var tamaño = [];
var y=0;
for(y=0;y<result.rows.length;y++)
{
     tamaño.push(result.rows[y].code);
}

//El array tamaño se carga con 0:1, 1:1, 2:1; 3:0, 4:0, 5:0
//donde 0,1,2,3,4,5 son los indices y 1, 0 son los valores que pueden variar, ej 4301, 9943
            
var counts = [];
                        
console.log(counts)
                    
tamaño.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x]||0) + 1;}); 

//por cada objeto del array cuento cuantos 0s y 1s hay. Me da como resultado 0:3,1:3 .Es decir, el indice 0 tiene 3 registros y el indice 1 tambien.
                    
var MaxRows = Math.max.apply(null,counts);
```

al intentar obtener el maximo da error porque counts no devuelve indice, es decir, puedo acceder de esta manera al valor counts[0] pero no de la manera estandar.

[image: sample]

¿Cómo puedo obtener el maximo (count) cuyos ids se repiten mas veces?

Comment: ¿Qué pasa en caso de duplicados? Por ejemplo el 5480 y el 5482 tienen el valor 8

Comment: Si está duplicado, tomaría solo uno de los dos valores independientemente del id.

Comment: Intenta entonces `counts.indexOf(Math.max(...counts))`